# Error Message: This report could not access its data source. please contact <Developer>, the author. But i have access to the datasource (gateway)

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-datasource

I have made a Power BI Dashboard with Analysis Services (Live Connection). I have full access to the database and in Power Bi Desktop everything works (all data is visible and updated).
Then, when I publish the dashboard, and go to app.powerbi.com to open the DB, it gives me the error message that it cannot access the data source. "This report could not access its data source. please contact , the author, to have it fixed." However, the gateway is set correctly and also connected to the corresponding dataset. I've already delete and re-create the role in the database. What is noticeable is that the update date right after the publishing says: 1.1.53, 00:53:28. After the first gateway update it shows the correct date and time. Can anyone help me to fix the problem? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign all of the end users read/write roles on the Tabular model.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).